# customize Jquery datepicker for date selection?

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I am using datepicker for the selection of start date and end date of an event.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
});

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" id="datepicker2">
```

Now both the date pickers are working fine except I want to restrict `datepicker2` to not allow any dates less that the date already selected for `datepicker`

Comment: "wanted to restrict datepicker 2 for the date seelction previous to the datepicker1 ??" means?? Datepicker1 will select value ,then what behaviour you expect from datepicker2 ?

Comment: @PratikJoshi yes!!!!!!

Comment: what you want from datepicker2 ??????

Comment: @PratikJoshi as you have mentioned above in your first comment

Comment: @Mehar but what you want from dtepicker 2 ???????

Comment: datepicker2 selects the end date of the event and that should not less then the start date selected from the datepicker1

Answer (score 0):

You can try these too

```
$(function() {

    $('#datepicker, #datepicker2').datepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        beforeShow: customRange,
        dateFormat: "dd M yy",
    });

});

function customRange(input) {

    if (input.id == 'datepicker2') {
        var minDate = new Date($('#datepicker').val());
        minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1)

        return {
            minDate: minDate

        };
    }

    return {}

}
```

Copied From [jQuery UI Datepicker Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827425/jquery-ui-datepicker-range)